# Kendo TabStrip doesn't retain scroll position

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I am migrating our project for telerik extension to kendo UI. In kendo's TabStrip I am facing a problem that whenever I change the tab state page does not retain its scroll position. This was not case with telerik extension for MVC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific? Like, describe a specific example.. or show some code.

Comment: I added a tabstrip like :-

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. You can either enable animation or use some custom JQuery to remove the anchor behaviour:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TabStrip1").children(".k-tabstrip-items").find(".k-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

See here for more info:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/browser-scroll-position-is-changed-when-tab-is-changed